# Getting errors while trying to added a Material Ui component with AMP

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js, amp-html

I made a very simple page to test AMP with Material UI and Next JS, However, when I try to render this page

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'

const TestAmp = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Hello World
                <Button >
                    LOGIN
                </Button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestAmp

export const config = { amp: true }
```

I get the following error:

```
/testamp  error  The parent tag of tag 'style amp-custom' is 'div', but it can only be 'head'.     https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml/#stylesheets
          error  The parent tag of tag 'style amp-custom' is 'div', but it can only be 'head'.     https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml/#stylesheets
          error  The parent tag of tag 'style amp-custom' is 'button', but it can only be 'head'.  https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amphtml/#stylesheets
```

And this is the generated HTML how it looks like
[Generated HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MNSb.jpg)

what could be the problem here ? specially that I just added a very simple component here with no styling

Comment: Where are you using `testamp`. It should start with uppercase.

Comment: Edited but that is not the point, I created this for a quick test because the whole project is getting all these errors

Comment: Please post the generated HTML. That file is the truth file; how you got there is irrelevant.

Comment: @JayGray Thank you for the comment, I updated the question and posted the generated HTML in an Image